# Trying to add an Object to an arrayList specified elsewhere

Tags: c#, object, arraylist

Whilst trying to make a class which I can use to add any object to an ArrayList from outside it I ran in to this problem:

```
public class AddToArrayList
   {
       public ArrayList stack;
      

       public void Push(int obj)
       {

           stack.Add(obj);
       }
}


internal class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
var add = new AddToArrayList;
add.Push(1);
add.Push("Hello");}
```

There is an error for me when trying to compile this code, an issue with retrieving the obj.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ArrayList` in this day and age....

Comment: _"There is an error for me"_ - you never set `this.stack = new ArrayList()`. You'll get a `NullReferenceException` otherwise.